# Multiple Base64 encoded parameters that appear as 1 in a URL query string

Tags: asp.net

I need to pass 2 parameters in a query string but would like them to appear as a single parameter to the user. At a low level, how can I concatinate these two values and then later separate them? Both values are Base64 encoded.

```
?Name=abcyxz
```

where both abc and xyz are separate Base64 encoded strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use some separator or store the length of the first item.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a valid separator that doesn't need to be encoded (a valid character in a query string that isn't found in a Base64 encoded string.)

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just encode the separator with the data, and split it after you've decoded it?

Answer (score 4):

why don't you just do something like this

```
temp = base64_encode("var1=abc&var2=yxz")
```

and then call

```
?Name=temp
```

Later you can decode the whole string and split the vars.
(sry for pseudo code :P)

Edit: a small quote from wikipedia

> The current version of PEM (specified in RFC 1421) uses a 64-character alphabet consisting of upper- and lower-case Roman alphabet characters (A–Z, a–z), the numerals (0–9), and the "+" and "/" symbols. The "=" symbol is also used as a special suffix code. The original specification, RFC 989, additionally used the "*" symbol to delimit encoded but unencrypted data within the output stream.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that the source data is more restricted (it cannot be a generic byte[], you should care about separators).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would be curious as to why you can't just pass two parameters.  But with that as a given, just choose any character that's a valid character in a URL query string, but won't show up in your base64 encoding, such as ~